# headers from apache to nginx after authentication

Tags: apache, nginx, header, openid-connect, proxypass

I have Nginx server that sends request to Apache server for protected content, Apache inturn forwards to Azure ADFS, for Azure ADFS authentication with Apache mod_auth_openidc is used.

While Below works fine :

`Apache:443/ourapp -> Apache:6000 -> Azure ADFS -> Apache:6000 -> Apache:443/ourapp`

But as soon as nginx is introduced in the setup as below, Error in browser pops-up "Non empty header(se_custid/ein) not found in the request to proceed"

`Nginx:443/ourapp -> Apache:6000-> Azure ADFS -> Apache:6000 -> Nginx:443/ourapp`

Apache config:

```
<Location /ourapp>
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require valid-user
</Location>

LoadModule auth_openidc_module modules/mod_auth_openidc.so
OIDCProviderMetadataURL https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX_XXX-xxx-XXXXXX/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
OIDCClientID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
OIDCClientSecret XXXXXXXXXX
OIDCRedirectURI https://forever-authcheck.tire1network.com:6000/ourapp 
OIDCCryptoPassphrase XXXXXXXXXXXX
OIDCScope "openid email profile"
#OIDCRemoteUserClaim email
OIDCProviderAuthorizationEndpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX_XXX-xxx-XXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
OIDCProviderTokenEndpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXXX_XXX-xxx-XXXXXX/oauth2/v2.0/token
#OIDCPKCEMethod S256

OIDCPassIDTokenAs claims
OIDCCookiePath /
OIDCCookieDomain forever-authcheck.tire1network.com
OIDCCookie APP-OIDC-SESSION
OIDCCookieHTTPOnly On
OIDCSessionInactivityTimeout 600
OIDCSessionMaxDuration 36006

<VirtualHost *:6000>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/voidcerror.log
    LogLevel debug
    ServerName forever-authcheck.tire1network.com

    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
    Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"
    
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    Header set ein %{OIDC_CLAIM_EIN}e
    ProxyPass /ourapp/ forever-authcheck.tire1network.com/in/
    ProxyPassReverse /ourapp/ forever-authcheck.tire1network.com/in/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName  forever-authcheck.tire1network.com
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/outcert/Certificate.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/outcert/CertificateKey.pem"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/pki/outcert/CertificateChain.p12"
</VirtualHost>
```

Nginx config :

```
nginx:80


location /ourapp/ {
  proxy_ssl_server_name on;
  proxy_pass https://forever-authcheck.tire1network.com:6000;
  proxy_set_header se-journey "direct";
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $remote_addr;
  proxy_redirect default;
  

  proxy_ssl_certificate     /etc/pki/outcert/Certificate.pem;
  proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/outcert/CertificateKey.pem;
  proxy_ssl_verify       off;
}
```

Question : how to forward correct headers from apache to nginx

Interesting headers apache using which i think needs to be forwards to nginx are "{OIDC_CLAIM_EIN}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright did bit of tshoot around the understanding, deployed another temp setup to understand dig more logs.

Here is the current understanding User Request ->  Nginx:443/ourapp -> Apache:6000-> Azure ADFS -> **Azure Returns URL to browser**  -> **Browser Requests the returned URL**

By looking at the logs closely, it was clear what's happening,
More over this one helped it to understand it [more](https://github.com/zmartzone/mod_auth_openidc/blob/master/src/mod_auth_openidc.c)

After tweaking ngnix to send right headers with port and right Host,

`proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port "443";`

`proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host "forever-authcheck.tire1network.com";`

which resulted in right cookie settings for original_url, by apache and mod_auth_openidc.

Now the redirection works correctly, Claims are reaching to NGINX and to our App.